# Proof that a similarity of the plane is bijective

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am reading Armstrong's [Groups and Symmetry](http://www.springer.com/gb/book/9780387966755), which uses a lot of geometric examples. One example is similarities of the plane (problem 2.4). Intuitively, I can see why similarities are bijective. They are one-to-one because the kernel is zero (since the only thing that would map to a line of zero length is a line of zero length). They are surjective since any line (or shape) is the similarity of another line (or shape). I can't find a formal proof of this though. I would appreciate if someone could show me or direct me to a formal proof.

Regards

Comment: Rigorous proofs of such properties are made of linear algebra: invertible matrices, determinants, and the like. It's a bit off track if you are reading about groups and symmetries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One has to start with a rigorous definition of a similarity (which the book unfortunately doesn't provide). One can define a similarity of the plane as a map $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ of the form

$$f(v) = rA\cdot v + t,$$

where $A \in O_2(\mathbb{R})$ is a $2 \times 2$ orthogonal matrix, $r > 0$ is a positive real number, and $t \in \mathbb{R}^2$ is a translation vector. The composition of the similarities $f(v) = rA \cdot v + t$ and $g(v) = sB \cdot v + u$ yields the similarity

$$ g(f(v)) = sB \cdot (rA \cdot v + t) + u = srBA \cdot v + sB \cdot t + u.$$

In particular, we see that, as an inverse of $f$, one can (and must) take the similarity

$$f^{-1}(v) = r^{-1}A^{-1} \cdot v - r^{-1}A^{-1} \cdot t.$$

So similarities are invertible, or, equivalently, they are bijective. In fact, we have shown that the set of similarities of the plane forms a group. It contains the Euclidean group (rigid motions of the plane), and it is a subgroup of the affine group.